# Why is `TOML.stringify()` output different for equivalent JSON input

Tags: javascript, json, toml

[`TOML.parse()`](https://github.com/LongTengDao/j-toml/tree/master/docs/English/#tomlparse) seems to output a JSON object that somehow "remembers" the original TOML formatting. When the JSON is sent back to [`TOML.stringify()`](https://github.com/LongTengDao/j-toml/tree/master/docs/English/#tomlstringify) the original formatting is preserved. However when this JSON is "purified" by stringifying and parsing back to JSON, the formatting is no longer preserved.

Origininal TOML:

```
# Tables defined in three different ways A,B,C:
parsedFromTomlA.titles = ['A1', 'A2']
parsedFromTomlB.titles = [
   'B1', 'B2'
]
[parsedFromTomlC]
titles = ['C1', 'C2']
```

`TOML.stringify(TOML.parse(toml))`:

```
parsedFromTomlA.titles = ['A1', 'A2']
parsedFromTomlB.titles = [
    'B1',
    'B2',
]
fromObjectLiteralD.titles = [
    'D1',
    'D2',
]

[parsedFromTomlC]

titles = ['C1', 'C2']
```

`TOML.stringify(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(TOML.parse(toml))))`:

```
parsedFromTomlA.titles = [
    'A1',
    'A2',
]
parsedFromTomlB.titles = [
    'B1',
    'B2',
]
parsedFromTomlC.titles = [
    'C1',
    'C2',
]
fromObjectLiteralD.titles = [
    'D1',
    'D2',
]
```

**How is j-toml "remembering" the format of the original TOML? How can I force j-toml to use a certain format for object literals that are added to the JSON?**

---

Test this code on [RunKit](https://npm.runkit.com/%40ltd%2Fj-toml):

```
var TOML = require("@ltd/j-toml")

const toml = `
parsedFromTomlA.titles = ['A1', 'A2']
parsedFromTomlB.titles = [
   'B1', 'B2'
]
[parsedFromTomlC]
titles = ['C1', 'C2']
`
const jsonParseToml = TOML.parse(toml)

// Add object literal.
jsonParseToml.fromObjectLiteralD = {
   titles: ['D1', 'D2']
}

// "Purify" JSON by converting to text, then back to JSON.
const jsonParseJson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonParseToml))

console.log('Objects appear the same:')
console.log('jsonParseToml', JSON.stringify(jsonParseToml, null, 4))
console.log('jsonParseJson', JSON.stringify(jsonParseJson, null, 4))

// Convert objects back to TOML.
const tomlOutParseToml = TOML.stringify(jsonParseToml, {newline: '\n'})
const tomlOutParseJson = TOML.stringify(jsonParseJson, {newline: '\n'})

console.log('But TOML output is different:')
console.log('tomlOutParseToml', tomlOutParseToml)
console.log('tomlOutParseJson', tomlOutParseJson)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answered](https://github.com/LongTengDao/j-toml/discussions/27#discussioncomment-6199331) by library author:

> This library use `WeakMap` internal to remember object formats parsed by
> same library. For objects from `JSON.parse` or other way created, you
> may mark each object by helper functions provided by the library,
> because I didn't find a better way to know what coder want.
>
> See details in docs: [[link]](https://github.com/LongTengDao/j-toml/tree/master/docs/English#tomlsection-tomlinline-tomlmultiline-tomlmultilinearray-tomlmultilinebasic-tomlbasic-tomlliteral-tomlcommentfor-tomlcommentforthis-tomlissection-tomlisinline)

I was able to use the `TOML.Section()` helper to force `JSON.stringify()` to look more like `parsedFromTomlC`.

---

Interestingly, this may also explain why functions that require a serializable JSON object sometimes result in an error when passed output from `TOML.parse()`.